# How do I access a SQL Server database from a Perl script in Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, perl, odbc

I have a Perl script on a Linux (Ubuntu 8.10) machine and I need to write data to a SQL Server Database. I've been trying to use the DBD::ODBC module but I can't get it to connect. Where can I get a free/open source driver to use to use for the ODBC connection or is there another way to do this from Perl on Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I connect to SQL Server 2005 with the stack of [unixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/), [freeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) (this is the driver) and DBD::ODBC.

After you install these components, edit /etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini to read like this:

```
[DNS]
Description = my database
Driver = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so #path to freeTDS driver
Server = ServerName
Database = DatabaseName
Port = 1433 #sql server default port
TDS_Version = 9.0 #9.0 is sql server 2005
try domain login = yes
try server login = yes
nt domain = DOMAIN
```

If all goes well, you should be able to connect with:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:ODBC:DNS', "userName", "passWord");
```

Good luck!

Comment: Per http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm, your comment may be wrong.

Comment: @RobKinyon, can't say for sure as I haven't used this software stack in a very long time.  But this was working, with these settings, 7 years ago.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [DBD::Sybase](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DBD%3A%3ASybase&mode=all) module, at one point Sybase and MS SQL Server shared a common codebase.

You may also want to investigate the open source [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) libraries. See the FreeTDS FAQ Question "[Which Perl library should I use](http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#Which.Perl.library.should.I.use)".