# What is an easy way to read a sql server table into a hash in Perl?

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

I'd like a simple perl script / sub to read a sql server table into a hash, does anyone have a good script or snippet (with 'use's) that can do this given a connection string and table name?

Here's a template:

```
sub sqltable {    
    my ($connStr,$table) = @_;    
    my ($user, $password, $host) = ($connectstr =~ m|^(.*)/(.*)@(.*)$|); # or whatever    
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:???:$host",$user,$password, { RaiseError => 1 }); # replace ??? with good SQL Server equivalent
    $dbh-> ???; # anything good for this part?  LongTruncOk?  LongReadLen?    
    return $dbh->selectall_arrayref("select * from $table");    
}
```

Comment: Does that mean you didn't try anything at all yet? You simply want the complete source code?

Comment: The complete source code as in all 2-3 lines of it?  Yes.  selectall_hashref points to the 2nd or 3rd line.  The first couple lines would create and connect the DBI.  I've already made it work for Oracle, I was hoping someone had handy a Sql Server equivalent.  Can I uses straight DBI?  DBI::something?  Can a connection string be used directly or should it be parsed into pieces then passed to connect?  There is a simple answer to all of this that someone already knows, and I look forward to the knowing it soon too.

Comment: the connection string is database dependent, so parsing it can only lead to less portability

Comment: Which doesn't quite answer 'can it be used directly'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the solution you are looking for.

```
sub get_db {
  my ($server,$database,$tbl,$username,$password) = @_;
  my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$database",$username,$password); 
  die "Error connecting to database: Error $DBI::err - $DBI::errstr\n" unless defined($dbh);
  my $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("select * from $tbl");
  $dbh->disconnect;
  return $rows;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

See [selectall_hashref](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#selectall_hashref) in the Perl DBI page.

Comment: +1 Wow.  Would've saved me a lot of time if I'd known about that earlier!

Comment: That's a good part of it, thanks.  Now I just need help on the first part - how to connect to the sql server given a connection string.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding connecting to SQL Server using Perl,

- If you're on a Windows machine, see: [How do I connect to a MSSQL database using Perl’s DBI module in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202962/how-do-i-connect-to-a-mssql-database-using-perls-dbi-module-in-windows)
- If you're on Linux, see: [How do I access a SQL Server database from a Perl script in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877413/how-do-i-access-a-sql-server-database-from-a-perl-script-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

You are exactly describing [Tie::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Tie-DBI/lib/Tie/DBI.pm). The `tie` facility in Perl allows native data structures (such as arrays and hashes) to represent data that comes from other mechanisms, such as databases and files.

That said, there's a lot of reading you can do on the general subject of database access and management in Perl. There are many full-fledged ORMs available, such as [Rose::DB::Object](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Rose::DB::Object), as well as simpler libraries like [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI) for connecting to a DB.